# How to detect if C code (which needs 'extern C') is compiled in C++

Tags: c++, c, extern

I have a C header as part of a C++ library.

This C header would only make sense compiled by a C compiler, or by a C++ compiler within an `extern "C" { ... }` block, otherwise unresolved link errors would happen.

I thought to add a block such as:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#error "Compiling C bindings with C++ (forgot 'extern \"C\"'?)"
#endif
```

in the C header, but unfortunately the `__cplusplus` macro is defined also within an `extern "C" { ... }` block.

Is there another way to detect this condition correctly?

Comment: You mean detecting the C++ part and check that extern was declared? No way to detect this. Just put the extern C.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

The common practice is not to demand client code wraps your header in `extern "C"`, but to do so conditionally yourself. For instance:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

  // Header content

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

That way client code is automatically correct without doing anything beyond including the header.

Comment: I don't know C++ ... Is there any issue with nested `extern "C" { /* ... */ extern "C" { /* ... */ } /* ... */ }`

Comment: @pmg - Not in C++. If you nest language linkage specifications, the innermost "wins". The macro is just to prevent a C compiler from rightfully rejecting the `extern "C"`.

Comment: @Rakete1111 - We shouldn't throw stones from our glass house that has no `restrict` qualifier :P

Comment: @StoryTeller: You mean you haven't thrown right through restrict yet?

Comment: Such a shame that C doesn't support extern "C"?  This makes zero sense to me.  Doesnt the keyword tell C++ to not use name mangling for the C symbols?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - It also tells it to adhere to a C calling convention (those may differ). And the point that was made is that it'd be nice if C compilers didn't reject the syntax outright, but instead treated it as a no-op. So the macro business won't be needed.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Well, the syntax *is* strange. I don't think there is much surprise that C doesn't want to support it. C++ could have adopted a new keyword, e.g. `_C_extern` or something like that, and it would have been easier for C to treat that as a synonym for `extern` (maybe with a macro...), and then support the `extern{}` grouping syntax.

Comment: @StoryTeller : It would then probably break old code which used it as a function or variable name...

Comment: names with _Capital are not allowed to use anyway

Comment: @RiaD - I don't know to which of my comments you are referring to. I don't believe I touched on reserved identifiers at any point.

Comment: @StoryTeller I believe RiaD was replying to vsz's comment about breaking old code. I'd like to add that one can definitely use identifier with leading underscore and capital, but at their own peril, because doing this produces non-compliant code that may be broken in the future.

Comment: @jxh Language linkage supports more than just `"C"` and `"C++"`; compilers are free to support any toerh language linkage specification. I'd say using a string literal for this is better than introducing a new keyword for each.

Comment: @Angew: That's an opinion I don't happen to share. An alternative syntax could have involved using a #pragma, that would have been ignored by a C compiler.

Comment: @RiaD: My suggestion was for the language to make it a standard.

Comment: as joH1 said my comment was to vsz